# CSS code doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I used the CSS3 Toolkit to generate a code but when I paste it in my editor it doesn't return the shape, in fact, it does't return anything on the screen. Can someone spot where I've gone wrong, please. It has nothing to do with how the css file is linked, because it works for my other css code. Just this particular code which I have generated with the CSS3 Toolkit which I've bought from App Store doesn't work.

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexcss.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" href="dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ToolKitStyle"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    .ToolKitStyle{
    background-color: #2EC0FE;
    -moz-border-radius: 34px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 34px;
    border-radius: 34px;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 4px 9px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 4px 9px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow:inset 0px 4px 9px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,4,5) 0%, rgb(246,107,255) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,4,5) 0%, rgb(246,107,255) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,4,5) 0%, rgb(246,107,255) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,4,5) 0%, rgb(246,107,255) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,4,5) 0%, rgb(246,107,255) 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add width and height in your css

```
.ToolKitStyle{
    background-color: #2EC0FE;
    -moz-border-radius: 34px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 34px;
    border-radius: 34px;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 4px 9px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 4px 9px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow:inset 0px 4px 9px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,4,5) 0%, rgb(246,107,255) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,4,5) 0%, rgb(246,107,255) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,4,5) 0%, rgb(246,107,255) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,4,5) 0%, rgb(246,107,255) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,4,5) 0%, rgb(246,107,255) 100%);
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Its strange why it didn't put the width and height into the code. It worked. :]

Answer (score 1):

Your JS is not linked correctly. Use `src` not `href`

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

As  regards your CSS issue -

You do not have any content, that's why you css does not appear to work.

Here is is with height, width  defined

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/73t6R/

Comment: Person who downvoted - Please explain, if you downvote an answer at least have the decency to comment

Comment: thanks for the post, but that wasn't the issue. It works with href regardless, I didnt have the width and height

Answer (score 1):

You needed to either put something inside the  or set width/height :
http://jsfiddle.net/2qyEP/

```
.ToolKitStyle{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #2EC0FE;
    -moz-border-radius: 34px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 34px;
    border-radius: 34px;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 4px 9px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 4px 9px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow:inset 0px 4px 9px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,4,5) 0%, rgb(246,107,255) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,4,5) 0%, rgb(246,107,255) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,4,5) 0%, rgb(246,107,255) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,4,5) 0%, rgb(246,107,255) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg , rgb(0,4,5) 0%, rgb(246,107,255) 100%);
}
```